# Matlab Array removing zero value

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, zero

I am new to MatLab and programming in general. I have been set the following problem:

4 players take part in a competition each person starts with 100 points.

Each person randomly plays another player.

If a player wins they get 1 point and the losing player loses 1 point from their total.

When a player has zero points they are elimated.

The game is over when there is only 1 player left.

I assume I need to create some sort of matrix array with 4 players and their 4 scores

A = [1 2 3 4; 100 100 100 100]

Is this correct and how would i remove a player and their score once it reaches zero.

Any help would be greatly recieved. Thanks

Comment: If you want to test your model, running this one-liner a few times should give you an indication of how many rounds are required for this game with two equal players: `r=min(find(abs(cumsum(2*(rand(1000000,1)>0.5)-1))>100))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, assuming you define A as such, you can remove the players with nonpositive score as such:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 100 100 0 100]
idx = A(2,:)<0.01 %To prevent suffering from rounding errors
A = A(:,~idx)
```

Comment: Another newbie question. The program i would have to write need to change the values from 100 some going up some going down. How do i change the values in the array/matrix? Eg it starts [ 1 2 3 4; 100 100 100 100] after one game the score could be [1 2 3 4; 101 100 99 100]

Comment: Hi @Stephen, welcome to SO. You really should post this as a new question. Each iteration you want an element to be incremented and another to be decremented. So you want to generate a matrix like I = [1 0 -1 0] with the 1 and -1 assigned randomly and then add it to A i.e. I + A(2, :).  A neat way to do it is to create a vector like [1 -1 0 0] or [1 -1 0] etc depending on the number of players left (I'm sure you can manage that) and then just call randperm on it. Try randperm([1 -1 0 0]) a few times in the command line to get an idea. Also if this is homework, please use the homework tag.

Comment: @Dan That should indeed do the trick. However, note that the homework tag has become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this page while looking for this answer myself (I'm also new to Matlab).
However, the above answers seem too complicated; Matlab's matrix addressing and assignment operators solve this problem very simply, as I found out after a bit of experimentation:

> > A = [1 2 3 4; 100 0 100 100]

A =
     1     2     3     4

100     0   100   100

> > A(:,A(2,:)==0)=[]

A =
     1     3     4

100   100   100

I hope this is useful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

The 1st answer is absolutely correct. However, in order to approach this problem, there is a straight-forward syntax built for this purpose, using `sparse` you will also be able to extract the player with 0-points directly:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 100 100 0 100]
ans= sparse (A(2,:))
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: This is just a different way of storing the information, try full(ans) and you will see that no player has been removed.

Comment: @Den: I know! but, the fact that one will be using 'ans' as the new matrix vector working with, solves the problem. I always use this method myself! I dont see anything wrong with this!

Comment: How would you then apply `randperm` depending on the number of players left as @Dan described?